# Function for increasing number after class up to max

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have a class change (with an increasing number) each time this function is called.

I currently have tried this:

```
function(i) { 
    if(i < 16) {
        $("#elm").removeClass("cls-" + (i));
        i++;
        $("#elm").addClass("cls-" + (i++));
    } else {}
}
```

New to jQuery so I'm not sure what to fix :/ Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function upOne(i) { 
    if(i < 16) {
            $("#elm").removeClass("cls-" + (i));  //if the number is always increasing by 1
            $("#elm").removeClass(); //if you want to remove everything

            $("#elm").addClass("cls-" + (++i));  //add 1 to i
    }
}
```

Here you go. This will remove the last number, and add on the new (next) number.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/XLfPX/

Comment: `$("#elm").attr("class", "");` => $("#elm").removeClass();

Comment: cheers.. `removeClass()` with no parameters remove all the class.. so i guess even the first line is not needed..:).. anywasy cheers. happy new year..:)

Comment: @bipen - Happy new year too. (Dec 31 didn't even start yet in US)

Comment: hmm I'm getting cls-NaN not sure what that means :/ I'm using this to call the function.. maybe you could adopt your fiddle with a single key of this? http://craig.is/killing/mice

Comment: ok and how about adding a minus when `b` is hit? To go the other way?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
function functionName(i) {   //you missed your function's name
  if(i < 16) {
    $("#elm").removeClass(); // this removes the whole class of that element
    i++;
    $("#elm").addClass("cls-" + (++i));  //this adds the class
  } else {
      //do your stuff here
   }
}
```